# Деструктор класса с полем структуры

Tags: c++, классы

Никак не могу написать деструктор для данноого класса

```
class Room_List
{

    node Node;

    public:


        Room_List()
        {
            Node.Current=NULL;
            Node.Next=NULL; 
        };
        void Add_to_Room_List( Room* room)
        {
            node *n=&(this->Node);
                while(n->Next!=NULL)
                    n=n->Next;

            if(n->Current!=NULL)
            {
            node *tmp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            tmp->Next=NULL;
            tmp->Current=room;
            n->Next=tmp;
            }
            else
            {
                n->Current=room;
                n->Next=NULL;
            }
        };
        ~Room_List()
        {
            node *N=&(this->Node);
            node *tmp=N;
            while(N->Next!=NULL)
            {
                N=N->Next;
                cout<<"tmp";//поиск места ошибки
                free(tmp);
                tmp=N;
            }
                cout<<"N error";//поиск места ошибки
            free(N);
        };
}; 
 //Room-другой класс
 class Room
{
friend class Room_List;
    protected:
        COORD OO;
        COORD XY;
        COORD_Matrix Doors;
        Character_Matrix Enemies;//здесь только поля без методов
//...
};
```

Хочу чтобы деструктор  освобождал память, выделенную  под указатели, но не объекты класса Room.
При вызове  деструктора возникает ошибка ( 3221226356 )
Возникает она в функции free();

Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый же `free` указывает на элемент в классе `Room_List::Node` . А память для него не выделялась.

Удалять нужно со второго элемента. Или , что правильнее `Node` сделать указателем, а не объектом. С первоначальным значением NULL.